# How to include image into css file using JSF tag

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have this css file which sets background image into JSF page:

```
body { padding: 35px; background: #4c4c4c url(images/grad1.png) 0 0 repeat-x; color: #fff; font: 11px/normal Arial, Helvetica; }
```

I want to use this tag in order to include the image as JSF resource:

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="grad1.png" />
```

How I can include the image into the css file as JSF resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your CSS file is loaded via `<h:outputStylesheet>`, use `#{resource}` mapping.

```css
body {
    padding: 35px; 
    background: #4c4c4c url(#{resource['images/grad1.png']}) 0 0 repeat-x; color: #fff; 
    font: 11px/normal Arial, Helvetica;
}
```